# Total de Registros SQL em todas as colunas

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Preciso retornar o total de registros da query em uma coluna, repetido mesmo, tipo isto:
[image: Tabela com Total]

Todavia, a query é meio chata. Uma query de 106 linhas, com vários SUM() e com um ORDER BY obrigatório. Não posso usar GROUP BY nesta query pois o nosso software que faz os tratamentos conforme o retorno da query

Um pedaço do código:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY B1_MASTER, B1_COD) AS ID,
   B1_COD,
   B1_DESC, 
   B1_CATEG, 
   B1_MASTER, 
   A2_COMPRAD,
   ISNULL((SELECT Sum(C6_QTDVEN * C6_PRCVEN) 
           FROM   SC6010 SC6, 
                  SF4010 SF4, 
                  SC5010 SC5 
           WHERE  C6_FILIAL = '01' 
                  AND C6_PRODUTO = B1_COD 
                  AND SC6.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' 
                  AND C5_FILIAL = C6_FILIAL 
                  AND C5_NUM = C6_NUM 
                  AND C5_EMISSAO BETWEEN '20160401' AND '20160404' 
                  AND C5_TIPO = 'N' 
                  AND C5_MODAL = '2'
```

Como eu faria isto? Preciso de um contador. Já uso o ROW_NUMBER porém nosso software não consegue pegar a última linha, infelizmente só consigo rodar linha por linha nele. Se eu conseguir o total de linhas mesmo que repetido em todas as colunas, já consigo usar o primeiro registro para pegar a informação que preciso

Abraços

Comment: Já descobri. Troquei o ROW_NUMBER por @@ROWCOUNT, resolvido

Comment: Olá Caio, você pode postar como resposta e aceitar sua própria resposta. Aproveite e faça um [tour] e entenda melhor como o SOpt funciona. :p

Comment: Confesso que mesmo com o Tour estou meio perdido para como aceitar a própria resposta, desculpe-me

Comment: Não tem problema. Em baixo possui um quadro para escrever a resposta. Depois de postar ela, você verá um ícone parecido com um certo (em baixo de onde mostra os pontos). Basta clicar nele. Mas primeiro você tem que criar uma resposta.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: Obrigado Randrade, pelo sistema fui informado que só posso aceitar minha própria resposta em 2 dias. Vou aguardar. E vou ficar aberto a opiniões também pro mesmo assunto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já descobri. Troquei o ROW_NUMBER por @@ROWCOUNT, resolvido